# Magento2 - How to display image inside dropdown?

Tags: magento2, dropdown-options

I want to display image inside drop down option like below image, Can anyone suggest me how can i achieve this?

[image]

Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks In Advance..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html Code

```
<div class="drop-down">
    <select name="options">
        <option class="en" value="en" 
       style="background-image:url('images/en.png');">English</option>
        <option class="fr" value="fr"
       style="background-image:url('images/fr.png');">French</option>
        <option class="nl" value="nl"
       style="background-image:url('images/nl.png');">Nederlands</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
jQuery().ready(function() {  
    /* Custom select design */    
    jQuery('.drop-down').append('<div class="button"></div>');    
    jQuery('.drop-down').append('<ul class="select-list"></ul>');    
    jQuery('.drop-down select option').each(function() {  
        var bg = jQuery(this).css('background-image');    
        jQuery('.select-list').append('<li class="clsAnchor"><span value="' + jQuery(this).val() + '" class="' + jQuery(this).attr('class') + '" style=background-image:' + bg + '>' + jQuery(this).text() + '</span></li>');   
    });    
    jQuery('.drop-down .button').html('<span style=background-image:' + jQuery('.drop-down select').find(':selected').css('background-image') + '>' + jQuery('.drop-down select').find(':selected').text() + '</span>' + '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="select-list-link">Arrow</a>');   
    jQuery('.drop-down ul li').each(function() {   
        if (jQuery(this).find('span').text() == jQuery('.drop-down select').find(':selected').text()) {  
            jQuery(this).addClass('active');       
        }      
    });     
    jQuery('.drop-down .select-list span').on('click', function()
    {          
        var dd_text = jQuery(this).text();  
        var dd_img = jQuery(this).css('background-image'); 
        var dd_val = jQuery(this).attr('value');   
        jQuery('.drop-down .button').html('<span style=background-image:' + dd_img + '>' + dd_text + '</span>' + '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="select-list-link">Arrow</a>');      
        jQuery('.drop-down .select-list span').parent().removeClass('active');    
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active');     
        $('.drop-down select[name=options]').val( dd_val ); 
        $('.drop-down .select-list li').slideUp();     
    });       
    jQuery('.drop-down .button').on('click','a.select-list-link', function()
    {      
        jQuery('.drop-down ul li').slideToggle();  
    });     
    /* End */       
});
```

Css

```
 .drop-down { 
    position: relative;  
    display: inline-block;    
    width: auto;       
    margin-top: 0;   
    font-family: verdana;    
 }      
 .drop-down select {   
    display: none;    
 }      
 .drop-down .select-list {   
    position: absolute;     
    top: 0;      
    left: 0;     
    z-index: 1;    
    margin-top: 40px;    
    padding: 0;         
    background-color: #595959;      
 }      
 .drop-down .select-list li {   
    display: none;      
 }    
 .drop-down .select-list li span {  
    display: inline-block;      
    min-height: 40px;        
    min-width: 280px;      
    width: 100%;        
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 35px;     
    background-color: #595959;     
    background-position: left 10px center;   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;       
    font-size: 16px;       
    text-align: left;       
    color: #FFF;        
    opacity: 0.7;      
    box-sizing: border-box;     
 }     
 .drop-down .select-list li span:hover,  
 .drop-down .select-list li span:focus {     
    opacity: 1;     
 }
```

Result

[image: Result]

Refrence: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-insert-images-to-select-dropdown-options

Comment: i have tried it, it works for me. Do you share your screenshot, what error it gives you?

Comment: Let me try I will notify you, if answer helpful I will accept and also upvote

Comment: sure, let me know if it works.

Comment: After spending the hour I found that  your solution is work for me..! Thanks +1 for you